# Возможно ли в C++ одноразовая инициализация переменных?

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть класс с `public` статическими переменными. Эти переменные нужно инициализировать 1 раз. Затем должна быть возможность читать их, но не изменять. Как можно организовать запрет изменения переменных?

Сделать **синглтон** (*придумать одноразовую какую-нибудь инициализацию..*) + запретить удаление, + переменные сделать `private` + на каждую переменную `get`-метод. Этот способ имеет право на существование, но а можно чтобы поля все же были `public` и чтобы нельзя было менять их?

Comment: И, кстати, инициализация всегда одноразовая. Дальнейшие изменения - это уже присваивание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявить переменные константами, инициализировать в конструкторе. Весьма тривиально.

```
class sample
{
public:
     const int var;
     sample(int value=9000):var(value) {}
}
```

Comment: О боже, насколько я глуп!)

Answer (score 3):

Для решения задачи достаточно объявить переменную со спецификатором `const`.

Можно воспользоваться нововведениями *C++11* - инициализацией членов в объявлении класса и ключевым словом `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int init() {
    return 100;
}

class A {
    public :
        static const int value = init();
}
```

Если же функцию инициализации невозможно вычислить на стадии компиляции, т.е. задать со спецификатором `constexpr`, то подойдёт "старый дедовский" способ:

```
int init() {
    return что_то_очень_сложное;
}

class A {
    public :
        static const int value;
};

const int A::value = init();
```